# How to Convert EPOCH UNIX datetime to SQL format with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have the following table with epch unix datetime stamps. Can someone let me know if there is SQL query or function that will allow me to convert / replace the the UNIX EPOCH time to SQL format

[image]

Comment: Far too much rep to make no attempt - a trivial search would find suggestions

Comment: And, of course, the duplicate posting on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/287c0194-4b96-432d-8a48-4fd8b379e249/how-to-query-unix-time-stamp-in-sql?forum=transactsql) to waste efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An epoch timestamp represents the number of seconds elapsed since January 1st, 1970. In SQL Server, you can use `dateadd()` to perform this computation:

```
dateadd(second, start_timeslot_unix, '19700101') start_timeslot_datetime
```

If your epochs are expressed in milliseconds instead of seconds, then: `dateadd(second, start_timeslot_unix / 1000, '19700101')`.

Comment: For that second scenario, `dateadd(millisecond, start_timeslot_unix, '1970-01-01')` also works.